# Forcing Riak to store data on distinct physical servers

Tags: replication, riak

I'm concerned by this note in Riak's documentation:

> N=3 simply means that three copies of each piece of data will be stored in the cluster. That is, three different partitions/vnodes will receive copies of the data. **There are no guarantees that the three replicas will go to three separate physical nodes**; however, the built-in functions for determining where replicas go attempts to distribute the data evenly.

https://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.3/learn/concepts/replication/#so-what-does-n-3-really-mean

I have a cluster of 6 physical servers with N=3. I want to be 100% sure that total loss of some number of nodes (1 or 2) will not lose any data. As I understand the caveat above, Riak cannot guarantee that. It appears that there is some (admittedly low) portion of my data that could have all 3 copies stored on the same *physical server*.

In practice, this means that for a sufficiently large data set I'm guaranteed to completely lose records if I have a catastrophic failure on a single node (gremlins eat/degauss the drive or something).

Is there a Riak configuration that avoids this concern?

Unfortunate confounding reality: I'm on an old version of Riak (1.4.12).

Comment: Riak does attempt to warn you if it hasn't worked out how to put all preflists on 3 physical machines.  When you run `riak-admin cluster plan` after adding all your nodes, you will get `WARNING: Not all replicas will be on distinct nodes` there will be 2 copies on one node.

Answer (score 1):

There is no configuration that avoids the minuscule possibility that a partition might have 2 or more copies on one physical node (although having 5+ nodes in your cluster makes it extremely unlikely that a single node with have more than 2 copies of a partition). With your 6 node cluster it is extremely unlikely that you would have 3 copies of a partition on one physical node.

The riak-admin command line tool can help you explore your partitions/vnodes. Running `riak-admin vnode-status` (http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/using/admin/riak-admin/#vnode-status) on each node for example will output the status of all vnodes the are running on the local node the command is run on. If you run it on every node in your cluster you confirm whether or not your data is distributed in a satisfactory way.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm hoping you can elaborate a bit on how I can use the output of vnode-status to put my mind at ease. I think I'm missing a step in the reasoning.  What I see from vnode-status is which vnodes live on which physical instance, and some details about the number of keys they manage and where that data resides on disk. Armed with this info, how do I answer my root question: how many keys are stored on the same physical node. In other words, how do I look at the vnodes on each host, and say "Ok, no physical host has all 3 vnodes for a given record".

Comment: Perhaps newer versions post 1.4.12 have different output? I see something along these lines:

VNode: 68507889249886074290797726533575766546371837952
Backend: riak_kv_bitcask_backend
Status:
[{key_count,934027},
 {status,[{"/var/lib/riak/bitcask/68507889249886074290797726533575766546371837952/347.bitcask.data",
           0,0,7122146},

Comment: If you run vnode-status for all of the nodes you should find that the value after the "VNode:" should exist in three places (hopefully on three different nodes) if your nval=3. If your ring size = 64 you should have 192 total VNode values after you run vnode-status on all 6 nodes.

Comment: That's odd. I ran `riak-admin vnode-status` on each server and put the output into 6 files locally. When I grep through them, "VNode: " occurs exactly 64 times with unique values each time. After a moment of terror, I was able to confirm that I have an N value of 3 for my production buckets. Can you think of something I may be doing wrong?